# add parenthesis to a phone number in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have a file with multiple contacts and I need to add parenthesis around the area code in the phone numbers. the format of the file is this.

```
Jenniffer Cowan:255-666-5645
Norma Corder:397-888-9999
```

and so on... if you could explain it in as much detail as you can that would be great. I know I need to use a `sed -e` command and that's about it.

Comment: which is the area code part?

Comment: Assume US phone number format: first three digits are the area code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the command:

```
sed -e 's/:\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-/:(\1)-/' infile >outfile
```

The regular expression in single quotes does this:

- searches for every occurence of a colon, followed by three digits, followed by a hyphen
- captures the three digits in a capture group
- substitutes the entire match with a colon, then a left paren, then the captured group, then a right paren, then a hyphen

It will do this for the first match in each line. If your line had many phone number fields, only the first one found would be changed.

Comment: Thank you, I understand completely.